# Unable to iterate over nodelist object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have following code, where I am trying to attache on click event handler by iterating over the Nodelist object "dateDisabled".

```
 var datesDisabled= document.getElementsByClassName('Val disabledDate');
  console.log(datesDisabled.length);// this outputs 7

  var d;

  for(d=0; d<=datesDisabled.length; d++)
     {
       datesDisabled[d].onclick=function(e) { 
   // above lines throws error   "datesDisabled[d] undefined"
          return false;
         }

      }
```

My question is why is this code showing the error "datesDisable[d] not defined" even though the length property has a value? I am aware of other ways of achieving this goal but wants to know what is wrong with this code.

Comment: Because `datesDisabled` will never have an element at `datesDisabled[7]`. Change `>=` to `>`. This assumes that the first seven iterations work, though; do they?

Comment: All array elements start with the index 0, so you shouldn't go till the length of the array, `(length-1)` is the max index possible,so you should loop till that point only. Change your loop condition should be `( d = 0; d<datesDisabled.length; d++ )`

Comment: @David Thomas: you are right, I knew index start at 0 but forgot the length property shows the absolute length. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given HTML such as the following:

```
<ul>
  <li class="demo">List-element 1</li>
  <li class="demo">List-element 2</li>
  <li class="demo">List-element 3</li>
  <li class="demo">List-element 4</li>
  <li class="demo">List-element 5</li>
</ul>
```

The following JavaScript will find five elements:

```
var demoElements = document.getElementsByClassName('demo');
```

```js
var demoElements = document.getElementsByClassName('demo');
snippet.log('Number of "demoElements" found: ' + demoElements.length);
```

```css
script + p[style]::before {
  content: 'Snippet Log:';
  display: block;
  color: #999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
script + p[style] {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  margin: 1em auto 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="demo">List-element 1</li>
  <li class="demo">List-element 2</li>
  <li class="demo">List-element 3</li>
  <li class="demo">List-element 4</li>
  <li class="demo">List-element 5</li>
</ul>
```

However, JavaScript uses zero-based indices in its arrays, therefore while the *length* of the NodeList is `5` the first element of the NodeList is at index `0`, and the last element is at index 4; more generically this can be explained as an Array (or NodeList, HTMLCollection etc) of ***n*** elements has elements as running from index ***0*** to index ***n - 1*** (this is true of Arrays, and so forth).

This can be demonstrated clearly enough in the following:

```
var haystack = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (var i = 0, len = haystack.length; i < len; i++) {
  console.log('Number ' + haystack[i] + ' found at index: ' + i);
}
```

```js
var haystack = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (var i = 0, len = haystack.length; i < len; i++) {
  snippet.log('Number ' + haystack[i] + ' found at index: ' + i);
}
```

```css
script + p[style]::before {
  content: 'Snippet Log:';
  display: block;
  color: #999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
script ~ p[style] {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0!important;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
script ~ p[style]:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0;
  border-top-width: 1px;
}
script ~ p[style]:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

In your posted code, rather than using the less-than operator (`<`) as the conditional you used the less-than-or-equal-to (`<=`); given that this operator in your loop evaluates both ***n-1*** and ***n*** (where ***n*** is the count of elements in the supplied NodeList) as being true, your loop attempts to access the ***n<sup>th</sup>*** array-element which, as noted, doesn't exist (given that the *last* element in the supplied NodeList (or HTMLCollection, Array and so on)) is at index ***n-1***; this results in the error you observed:

```
var haystack = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (var i = 0, len = haystack.length; i <= len; i++) {
  console.log('Number ' + haystack[i] + ' found at index: ' + i);
}
```

The last iteration of this loop returns the error (in Chrome/Windows 8.1):

```
Number undefined found at index: 5
```

```js
var haystack = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (var i = 0, len = haystack.length; i <= len; i++) {
  snippet.log('Number ' + haystack[i] + ' found at index: ' + i);
}
```

```css
script + p[style]::before {
  content: 'Snippet Log:';
  display: block;
  color: #999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
script ~ p[style] {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0!important;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
script ~ p[style]:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0;
  border-top-width: 1px;
}
script ~ p[style]:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

This occurs, predictably, because there is no array-element in the ***n<sup>th</sup>*** position.

So, the easiest way is to simply use either:

```
for (var index = 0, len = collection.length; index < len; i++)
```

Or:

```
for (var index = 0, len = collection.length; index <= len - 1; i++)
```

But, for ease-of-writing most people, including myself, use the former when a `for` loop is required.

Under ECMAScript 5, however, the easier way – in compliant browsers – is to simply use `Array.prototype.forEach()` to iterate over an Array:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].forEach(function (arrayElement, index, suppliedArray) {
  console.log(arrayElement + ' found at ' + index);
});
```

In the `forEach()` method, which loops over the supplied array, the arguments to the anonymous function are supplied automatically and are:

1. `arrayElement`: The array-element held at the current index of the array over which we're iterating,
2. `index`: The index of the array-element from the array over which we're iterating,
3. `suppliedArray`: A copy of the array itself supplied to the `forEach()` method.

Now, while the `forEach()` method is useful (in those browsers that support it) for iterating over Arrays, it can't be directly used on NodeLists or HTMLCollections (or anything that's Array-like, but not an Array) without the use of `Function.prototype.call()`:

```js
var demoElements = document.getElementsByClassName('demo');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(demoElements, function(demoElement) {
  demoElement.style.color = 'orange';
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="demo">List-element 1</li>
  <li class="demo">List-element 2</li>
  <li class="demo">List-element 3</li>
  <li class="demo">List-element 4</li>
  <li class="demo">List-element 5</li>
</ul>
```

The use of `Function.prototype.call()` allows us to assign the object we wish to treat as an array (here: `demoElements` as the first argument, and the second is the anonymous function which will be supplied to the `Array.prototype.forEach()` method.

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [Less-than-or-equal (`<=`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Less_than_or_equal_operator_(<)).
- [Less-than (`<`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Less_than_operator_(<)).

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
for(d=0; d<datesDisabled.length; d++)
```

`getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection which is **0 based** (i.e. a n member HTMLCollection would have indices 0, 1... , **n - 1**)

Comment: And now you need to explain your answer.

Comment: I thought it was a more of a Saturday night, aargh! I need coffee kind of question :-)

Comment: Perhaps so, for the OP, but for others browsing for solutions in the future — the people the questions and answers are supposed to help — answers should be a resource from which to learn. This may, or may not, be eligible for a canonical question, but regardless: an explanation is almost essential, otherwise there's no learning to be taken.

Answer (score 0):

How to construct a for loop [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
 console.log(i);
 // more statements
}


var datesDisabled= document.getElementsByClassName('Val disabledDate');

for(var d = 0; d < datesDisabled.length; d++){
  datesDisabled[d].onclick = function(e){ 
    return false;
  }
}
```